# Is there an SQL query I can use to satisfy a rather complicated set of criteria?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a simple option-based adventure game using PHP and a mySQL database in phpMyAdmin. I've got it set up so that events in the game are objects in a table called Events. The options you can choose at each event are in a table called Actions. The two have a many-to-many relationship, because some actions may be taken at multiple events. Therefore, I've created a junction table called EventActions. I can successfully query which actions should be available for an event with an inner join using that junction table:

```
public static function getActions($eventID){
        $db = Database::getDB();
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM eventactions ea
                INNER JOIN actions a ON a.actionID = ea.actionID
                WHERE ea.eventID = :eventID';
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(":eventID", $eventID);
        $statement->execute();
        $actions = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $actions;
    }
```

However, the situation gets sticky when I try to incorporate needing certain items to do certain actions. I'm also trying to incorporate needing to have done certain things for certain actions to show up. This has led me to make tables for Items, and Effects, and junction tables for itemActions and effectActions. So now my database query function needs to be much more complicated, and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around forumlating the query. I need a query that essentially gets from the database: All actions that are tied to the event given, and the items and worldeffects columns that are tied to that action. I attempted something like this, but it does not return any rows:

```
select * from eventactions ea
inner join actions a on a.actionID = ea.actionID
inner join actionitems ai on ai.actionID = a.actionID
inner join actioneffects ae on ae.actionID = a.actionID
inner join worldeffects e on e.effectID = ae.worldEffect
where ea.eventID = :event
```

What I want returned from this function is a list of all of the options that are available for a given event. For each option, I want the columns from the Action table, from the Items table (so I know which items this option requires) and from the Effects table (so I know what effect on the world an option has, and what world effects are required for an option to be available).

Let me know if I'm not including necessary information. Thanks!

Comment: Your query looks good, though I would have used `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. In any case, without some sample data it's difficult for us to guess what's wrong.

Comment: I did need to use a left join! I'm embarrassed I typed so much and this was the answer. Thank you!

Comment: And never use `SELECT *`